# Why my jigsaw's blade keeps on being bent?

Tags: wood, tools, powertools

I am using a t-shaped jigsaw blade on my 400W [PRAKTYL](https://www.leroymerlin.gr/gr/ergaleia/ilektrika-ergaleia/seges-spathoseges/sega-practyl-400w-62274436/) (link in Greek) jigsaw. I attempt to perform a cut, but the blade keeps on bending regardless how hard I try to place it straight:

[image: My jigsaw bent blade]

I used it to cut some mdf wood found in trash (apparentrly it was a piece of a bed). Whislst I was cutting the jigsaw kept on jumping and deviate from the line. Also, I noticed moke to coming out from the material being cut in the place it was cut (and not from the tool itself).

Do you know why that happens and how I can make my jigsaw blade to be placed perfectly in place.

Comment: It's hard to tell from that fuzzy photo, but is the blade outside its notch in the guide behind it? Why is the table tilted? How old (and worn out) is the saw? I'm not sure we can answer without seeing your technique. Something's binding.

Comment: Moke, (smoke) coming from the material is usually a sign of a dull  or wrong blade. Also from pushing the saw faster than it can cut. Jig saws are not meant to have the blade perfectly in place.

Comment: Looks like you are using a wood cutting blade to cut a metal rod. A metal cutting blade will have fine teeth.

Comment: I was looking at the guide also if the blade gets hot it will move away from the pressure (bend) make sure to use the correct type of blade for the material a fine tooth for metal and more like shark teeth for wood.

Comment: @JimStewart I think that the table for the saw and it's at an angle.

Comment: what is the silver thing across the top of the picture? ... why is it blocking the view of the blade?

Comment: @jsotola it is the plate where the jigsaw kisses the cutting surface that is about to cut.

Comment: @JimStewart I was cutting wood and not metal.